# Passing information between two class with one being MonoBehavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback

I want to pass data from `classA` to `classB` that extends MonoBehavior.

I created a method called activate as follows in my `classB`

```
public void  activate(String nameVal)
  {

  }
```

I called the above method using `ClassB.activate("data")`. but for some reason, it is never being called. How do I send a callback from classA to classB?

Comment: Where and how do you call it? How are you sure it is called? It does nothing .. you should probably at least add a log when the method was called... Could you add more code for context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs :

1) Make the activate() static. Just as in C#, you don't need reference to the object to call a static method.

2) If you fit the "one-object" requirement, you can use the Singleton Pattern.

There are quite a few tuto about it over the internet, so i won't extend on it too much but basically, you create a static variable containing your unique object, like this :

```
public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

You can have an idea of more advanced way to implement it in [this tutorial](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton).

EDIT :
It should be noted that it's quite a strange needs. Usually, it's the monobehaviours that control the other "simple" script. You may indeed need a callback, after a process in a non-monobehaviour, but in this case, the Script B has the references to classA.

So i add a **3)** a proper callback :

class B, containing MyCallback() (a proper method fitting the needs).

```
myObjectA.DoSomeProcess("data", MyCallback);
```

class A:

```
public void DoSomeProcess(string data, Action<string> callback)
{
    // Some process
    callback("data processed");
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the Singleton pattern is quite controversial and you always should use "real" references if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the method on `classA`.

`CallClassB` is not called.
If you're calling `CallClassB()`, then you can be fully sure that either `ClassB.activate("data");` will be called or you get a `NullReference Exception`.

```
public class classA
{
    public classB ClassB;

    //this method either:
    //OPTION 1 - calls ClassB.activate  
    //OPTION 2 - gets a NullReference Exception  
    public void CallClassB()
    {
        ClassB.activate("data");
    }
}
```

FURTHER NOTE:
It might be worth considering that in C# lowerCamelCase represents variables (as instances of a class), while UpperCamelCase is for Class.
Reading your comment it seems you're doing the opposite.

FURTHER NOTE 2:
This is not a callback. If we're talking about a callback we should mention events, listeners, delegates or any other possible callback. If this is your case the answer is:
**- Your callback has not been received by classB.**

Why depends on the callback not on the Method.

Comment: Use Uppercase for class names and lowercase for variables. `ClassB classB`